# Promoting serverfault.com to a user already using it

Tags: discussion, advertising

I'm already using ServerFault with the same OpenID login. What is the use of advertising me serverfault when I'm browsing on stackoverflow?

I'm taking ServerFault just as an example.

And yes, whenever a popular question of any other StackExchange site is displayed in the ads, it is very much tempting to be clicked and most of the times equally informative when visited. So that is surely useful.

Answer (score 2):

Erm, what? You mean that you want the algorithm that randomly advertises "hot questions" across the network to filter out ads from sites that you're already a member of? Putting aside the unnecessary complexity of such a per-user system, there's at least one other problem...

What if you haven't visited Server Fault in a while? You may not have *completely* forgotten about the site, but it's certainly slipped from your immediate memory and we want to remind you to come back! Seeing an interesting question, ideally one that you can answer yourself or one whose answers you might be interested in, is often a good enough enticement to get you to come visit the site again. And, of course, while you're there, you might contribute some other content as well.

Comment: I mean that it is good if the ad shows an interesting question with it. But I'm talking about server fault ad like this http://static.adzerk.net/Advertisers/2333.jpg without any question in it.